# Uncertainty for maximum (peak)

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

I have to find $\theta$s for which we get maximum values for this plot:
[image]

Let's take the first peak. I've found $\theta$ to be $26.1^o$. Now I have to determine its uncetrainty. The thing is that my professor told us to "think of something" for finding uncertainties. He's very fussy about anything in reports so I want to use a method that leaves nothing to complain about.

In my previous post I asked about normal distrubution for finding maxima - he didn't like it so I'm searching for something different.

So how do I find the uncertainties of $\theta$ for which we get these peaks?

EDIT: This is the first peak zoomed in.
[image]

Comment: Can you assume a particular shape for the curves or at least that the curves are  symmetrical about the peak?

Comment: I edited the answer so now it includes a zoomed plot of the 1st peak. I'm not sure what is prohibited and what's not though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These resonances are described by a Lorentzian distribution. So you can just fit this distribution. However, note that the result won't differ significantly from the result obtained by fitting a normal distribution -- which is available in most programs.

Your key problem is that you have only few datapoints per peak. Therefore, if you do not have a higher resolution in the dataset, and if you do not have a model, which describes the hole dataset simultaneously, you will obtain approx. the same result. A possible work-around would be to measure the same data several times, and obtaining $N=10$ "similar" dataset. Now, you could calculate the average peak location and its standard deviations (use the scaling factor $1/\sqrt{N-1}$, due to the central limit theorem).

An different method is called leave-one-out-cross-validation. It is often used for model selection. The key idea is similar to what I describe before you edited your question:

1. Choose a region around the peak, which contains $n$ datapoints,
2. Leave the $i^{th}$ datapoint out and fit the model,
3. Repeat step 2, and leave each datapoint out once.
4. Calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: The plot is showing dependancy of intensity on the wavelength (I know the x-axis is labeled as $\theta$ but that's related, we use a monocrystal as diffraction grating) for x-rays. I wanted to do something similar as you described but there's one obstacle - the peak has two points around it at most (they are connected by a line on the plot) so that doesn't make a good statistic.